# contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm getting following exception at run time randomly. How do I stop it happening?

**Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0)**

Code:

```
self.table.reloadData()
let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
self.table.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
self.table.isHidden = false
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, I think your table is empty. You are trying to scroll to the cell at `IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)` aka the first cell in the table, but because it is empty, there is no cell with `IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)`. Providing more info might clarify your question more.

Comment: Yes that's the logical conclusion, either table is empty or table is not loaded fully. I'm not sure what more info we need to look into it? It's just a table which I'm loading after reading data from JSON and scrolling to the top. Shall I check for the empty table before calling scrollToRow? What if table is not loaded fully? How to catch this scenario?

Comment: Well, if the table is empty, you don't really have to scroll to the top. So I think putting the `self.table.scrollToRow(...)` inside of an if statement to check if the amount of cells is > 0 is the best and easiest solution yes.

Comment: Tx, I've done that. Will see how it goes.